RF power transmission control in U-blox GSM modules
I am using the SARA-U270 GSM module and want to test energy-saving techniques. One technique I would like to try is power transmission control, adjusting the transmission power in dBm based on the quality of the signal. This involves decreasing the transmission power when the signal quality is good.
Is this possible with this u-blox module? I searched for AT commands in the u-blox general documentation, but couldn’t find anything relevant. Is  it is even possible?

Can you ask a specific question?

Power control is between your user equipment and the base station, not really in your control – in other words: in all likelihood, this is already done without you doing anything. It's very much in the interest of the mobile network that your module doesn't transmit any louder than necessary; it keeps the multi-user interference low and reduces the severity of the near-far problem in cellular communications.
